# missing observation panel data, bring forward value 20 periods

Tags: pandas

Here's to read in a DataFrame like the one I'm looking at

```
pd.DataFrame({
'period' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 19, 20, 21, 22,
            23, 25, 26],
'id' : [1285, 1285, 1285, 1285, 1285, 1285, 1285, 1285, 1285, 1285, 1285,
       1285, 1285, 1285, 1285, 1285, 1285, 1285, 1285, 1285],
'pred': [-1.6534775, -1.6534775, -1.6534775, -1.6534775, -1.6534775,
       -1.6534775, -1.6534775, -1.6534775, -1.6534775, -1.6534775,
       -1.6534775, -1.6534775, -1.6534775, -1.6534775, -1.6534775,
       -1.6534775, -1.6534775, -1.6534775, -1.6534775, -1.6534775],
'ret' : [ None, -0.02222222, -0.01363636,  0.        , -0.02764977,
          None, -0.00909091, -0.01376147,  0.00465116,     None,
        0.01869159,  0.    ,    0.         ,      None , -0.00460829,
        0.00462963,  0.02304147,  0.     ,       None, -0.00050756]})
```

Which will look like this when read in.

```
    period    id      pred       ret
0        1  1285 -1.653477       NaN
1        2  1285 -1.653477 -0.022222
2        3  1285 -1.653477 -0.013636
3        4  1285 -1.653477  0.000000
4        5  1285 -1.653477 -0.027650
5        8  1285 -1.653477       NaN
6        9  1285 -1.653477 -0.009091
7       10  1285 -1.653477 -0.013761
8       11  1285 -1.653477  0.004651
9       13  1285 -1.653477       NaN
10      14  1285 -1.653477  0.018692
11      15  1285 -1.653477  0.000000
12      16  1285 -1.653477  0.000000
13      19  1285 -1.653477       NaN
14      20  1285 -1.653477 -0.004608
15      21  1285 -1.653477  0.004630
16      22  1285 -1.653477  0.023041
17      23  1285 -1.653477  0.000000
18      25  1285 -1.653477       NaN
19      26  1285 -1.653477 -0.000508
```

pred is 20 period prediction and consequently I want to do is bring the returns back 20 days. (but do it in a flexible way.)

Here's the lag function I have presently

```
def lag(df, col, lag_dist=1, ref='period', group='id'):
    df = df.copy()
    new_col = 'lag'+str(lag_dist)+'_'+col

    df[new_col] = df.groupby(group)[col].shift(lag_dist)

    # set NaN values that differ from specified
    df[new_col] = (df.groupby(group)[ref]
                                 .shift(lag_dist)
                                 .sub(df[ref])
                                 .eq(-lag_dist)
                                 .mul(1)
                                 .replace(0,np.nan)*df[new_col])
    return df[new_col]
```

but when I run

```
df['fut20_ret'] = lag(df, 'ret', -20, 'period')
df.head(20)
```

I get

```
    period  id  pred           gain     fee       prc          ret   fut20_ret
0   1   1285    -1.653478   0.000000    0.87    1.000000    NaN         NaN
1   2   1285    -1.653478   -0.022222   0.87    0.977778    -0.022222   NaN
2   3   1285    -1.653478   -0.035556   0.87    0.964444    -0.013636   NaN
3   4   1285    -1.653478   -0.035556   0.87    0.964444    0.000000    NaN
4   5   1285    -1.653478   -0.062222   0.87    0.937778    -0.027650   NaN
6   8   1285    -1.653478   -0.022222   0.87    0.977778    NaN         NaN
7   9   1285    -1.653478   -0.031111   0.87    0.968889    -0.009091   NaN
8   10  1285    -1.653478   -0.044444   0.87    0.955556    -0.013761   NaN
9   11  1285    -1.653478   -0.040000   0.87    0.960000    0.004651    NaN
10  13  1285    -1.653478   -0.048889   0.87    0.951111    NaN         NaN
11  14  1285    -1.653478   -0.031111   0.87    0.968889    0.018692    NaN
12  15  1285    -1.653478   -0.031111   0.87    0.968889    0.000000    NaN
13  16  1285    -1.653478   -0.031111   0.87    0.968889    0.000000    NaN
15  19  1285    -1.653478   -0.035556   0.87    0.964444    NaN         NaN
16  20  1285    -1.653478   -0.040000   0.87    0.960000    -0.004608   NaN
17  21  1285    -1.653478   -0.035556   0.87    0.964444    0.004630    NaN
18  22  1285    -1.653478   -0.013333   0.87    0.986667    0.023041    NaN
19  23  1285    -1.653478   -0.013333   0.87    0.986667    0.000000    NaN
```

How can I modify my lag function so that it works properly? It's close but I'm struggling on the last little bit.

Comment: Your are asking a shift of 20 on a dataframe with only 20 rows, hence, `df.groupby(group)[col].shift(lag_dist)` is going to return all nan's

Comment: Sorry there are actually more rows than that, I just thought copying more over would be excessive